# Strange problem with c# .net core calling terminal on Macos

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

When I use C# to execute Mac Os built-in commands, such as "ls" command, I can normally return the result of command line as follows:

```
string mediaInfo = "";
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("ls");
start.Arguments = "-i";
start.CreateNoWindow = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
start.RedirectStandardInput = true;
start.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p=Process.Start(start);
StreamReader reader = p.StandardOutput;
string line = reader.ReadLine();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    line = reader.ReadLine();
    mediaInfo = line + mediaInfo;
}
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
reader.Close();
return mediaInfo;
```

The above code can return the execution result of the "ls" command, but when I changed the "ls" command to "ffmpeg", nothing was returned. The code is as follows :(I have installed ffmpeg correctly and executed successfully on the command line)

```
string mediaInfo = "";
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg");
start.Arguments = "-i";
start.CreateNoWindow = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
start.RedirectStandardInput = true;
start.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p=Process.Start(start);
StreamReader reader = p.StandardOutput;
string line = reader.ReadLine();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    line = reader.ReadLine();
    mediaInfo = line + mediaInfo;
}
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
reader.Close();
return mediaInfo;
```

Does anybody know what this is about? Thank you very much!

Comment: What result do you expect? I don't think ffmpeg writes to standard out.

Comment: When I run "ffmpeg -i xxx.mp3" on the terminal, it will return the detailed information of "xxx.mp3". I hope to get this result in C#, thank you!

Comment: When you do it from c# does the command otherwise work?

Comment: It seems you meant `start.Arguments = "-i xxx.mp3"`, right? Did you forget to provide the MP3 file name? Also, try to read from [StandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=netcore-2.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_StandardError) as well, remember to set `RedirectStandardError = true` before hand.

Comment: Yes, when I run "ffmpeg  -I  xxx.avi -vcodec mpeg4 -s 1920*1080 test.mp4" with C#, it works and generates the correct files, but I can't get any information return from the command line.

Comment: And I add the parameter RedirectStandardError = true, but nothing seems to have changed.